# Create image from text (incorrect size)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage

I am creating an image from a `UIlablel`‘s text in a `UIView` subclass. The `UIlablel`‘s text is set in `awakeFromNib` and will be different everytime the app launches. The only place that the image captures the entire `UIlablel`‘s text is in `layoutSubviews` —> due to frame sizes I believe. Notice in my code below that I am relying on the `bounds` on the label's parent view. The problem is that `layoutSubviews` is called multiple times so this image might be created many times. I tried to capture the image in `didMoveToWindow` and other places, but only a portion of the `UIlablel`‘s text is captured. This is code to make image: Any thoughts?

```
func createImage(withText text: NSAttributedString, inParent parent: UIView) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, false, 0)
    text.draw(in: parent.bounds)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
}
```

Comment: Can you check size and origin of parent.bounds and frame?

Comment: Save text from your UILabel one time and then redraw UIImage each time layoutSubview call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that layoutSubviews is called multiple times so this image might be created many times

But that is why you have been given the `if` statement, so that you can make sure the image is only created *once*.

```
var createdImage = false
func createImage( ... {
    if !createdImage {
        createdImage = true
        // create image
    }
}
```

Comment: This is why matt is matt, thanks! I was doing something similar to this but my code needed some serious refactoring and that was making it seem more difficult to me than it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use another variable to know if layoutSubviews have been called.

```
var layoutInvoked = false

func layoutSubviews () -> (Void)
{
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if layoutInvoked == false
    {
        layoutInvoked = true
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

I don't know if there is easier way, but this one does job for me.